# cmake project: undefined reference to 'xxx'

Tags: c, gcc, arm, clion, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile CLion Project.

[image: the Project looks like this]

and the CMakeList.txt

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

# specify cross-compilers and tools
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_AR arm-none-eabi-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set(SIZE arm-none-eabi-size)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# project settings
project(main_board C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

#Uncomment for hardware floating point
add_compile_definitions(ARM_MATH_CM4;ARM_MATH_MATRIX_CHECK;ARM_MATH_ROUNDING)
add_compile_options(-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16)
add_link_options(-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16)

#Uncomment for software floating point
#add_compile_options(-mfloat-abi=soft)

add_compile_options(-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork)
add_compile_options(-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -fmessage-length=0)

# uncomment to mitigate c++17 absolute addresses warnings
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-register")

# Enable assembler files preprocessing
add_compile_options($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM>:-x$<SEMICOLON>assembler-with-cpp>)

if ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Release")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "RelWithDebInfo")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast -g)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for size")
    add_compile_options(-Os)
else ()
    message(STATUS "Minimal optimization, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Og -g)
endif ()

include_directories(Core/Inc USB_DEVICE/App USB_DEVICE/Target Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS_V2 Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include Drivers/CMSIS/Include Middlewares/ST/ARM/DSP/Inc)
include_directories(Core/app/Inc Core/app/protocol Core/bsp/Inc Core/components/algorithm Core/components/algorithm/Include Core/components/controller Core/components/devices Core/components/support)

add_definitions(-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F407xx -DARM_MATH_CM4 -D__FPU_PRESENT=1U -DARM_MATH_MATRIX_CHECK -DARM_MATH_ROUNDING)
add_definitions(-Wno-attributes) # ignore warning: 'packed' attribute ignored'

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "startup/*.*" "Library/*.*" "Middlewares/*.*" "Drivers/*.*" "USB_DEVICE/*.*" "Core/*.*")

set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F407IGHx_FLASH.ld)

add_link_options(-Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map)
add_link_options(-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork)
add_link_options(-T ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${SOURCES} ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE}
Building ${BIN_FILE}")
```

As soon as i try to include the `arm_math.h` and into my CLion Project i get a ton of: main.cpp:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to glViewport error messages and building my main.cpp in the base dir fails.

As soon as i try to call the function defined in `arm_math.h`. it will ton of error: `undefined reference to 'xxx'`

At the same time, another project of mine has the same problem. It cannot use the static library file correctly.

```
FAILED: main_board.elf 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\GNUARM~1\102021~1.07\bin\AR19DD~1.EXE -O3 -DNDEBUG -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage,-Map=C:/Users/Cjsah/Desktop/rm/final/main_board/build/main_board.map -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -T C:/Users/Cjsah/Desktop/rm/final/main_board/STM32F407IGHx_FLASH.ld @CMakeFiles\main_board.elf.rsp -o main_board.elf  && cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\Cjsah\Desktop\rm\final\main_board\build && arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Oihex C:/Users/Cjsah/Desktop/rm/final/main_board/build/main_board.elf C:/Users/Cjsah/Desktop/rm/final/main_board/build/main_board.hex && arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Obinary C:/Users/Cjsah/Desktop/rm/final/main_board/build/main_board.elf C:/Users/Cjsah/Desktop/rm/final/main_board/build/main_board.bin""
c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/main_board.elf.dir/Core/app/Src/chassis_behaviour.c.obj: in function `chassis_behaviour_control_set':
chassis_behaviour.c:(.text.chassis_behaviour_control_set+0x6c): undefined reference to `arm_sin_f32'
c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/main_board.elf.dir/Core/app/Src/chassis_task.c.obj: in function `chassis_task':
chassis_task.c:(.text.chassis_task+0x2da): undefined reference to `arm_sin_f32'
c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: chassis_task.c:(.text.chassis_task+0x2ec): undefined reference to `arm_cos_f32'
c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/main_board.elf.dir/Core/app/Src/gimbal_task.c.obj: in function `gimbal_feedback_update.constprop.0':
gimbal_task.c:(.text.gimbal_feedback_update.constprop.0+0x7a): undefined reference to `arm_cos_f32'
c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: gimbal_task.c:(.text.gimbal_feedback_update.constprop.0+0x8c): undefined reference to `arm_sin_f32'
```

It looks like, that CLion just dose not link find the right `arm_cortexM4l_math.lib` in my own program. if I include it from `arm_math.h`. Is the problem caused by the compiler or because I wrote fewer statements?

Comment: Don't you have to add the appropriate library to your CMakeList.txt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)